# Artisan Migration trouble

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

Okay, so I'm trying to migrate my database, I've got mysql and everything else set up properly.
But when I went to my SSH Console and typed in " php artisan migrate:install " I got the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Laravel\Bundle' not found in /Solder/laravel/cli/artisan.php on line 12
```

So I went to artisan.php to find out what the problem was and this is the code in it lines 1-12 of 49

```
<?php namespace Laravel\CLI; defined('DS') or die('No direct script access.');

use Laravel\Bundle;
use Laravel\Config;
use Laravel\Request;

/**
 * Fire up the default bundle. This will ensure any dependencies that
 * need to be registered in the IoC container are registered and that
 * the auto-loader mappings are registered.
 */
Bundle::start( 'Bundle' );
```

Any idea whats wrong with it?
I've also got /Solder/ set up as the root document, so Laravel\Bundle should be /Solder/Laravel/bundle.php right?
Also, if you need any additional information about it just mention it in your answer and I'll provide it if I can.

Comment: Why your `laravel\bundle` in lowercase? Change it to `Laravel\Bundle`

Comment: I edited the file in my question and on my server, same error message is there.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, you HAVE set up your database.php file under config, correct? That is, the connection array?

Comment: 'mysql' => array(
   'driver'   => 'mysql',
   'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
   'database' => 'solder',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'mickeymouse',
   'charset'  => 'utf8',
   'prefix'   => 'solder',
  ),

Comment: That thing right? If so then yes, I have.